# C99 Segmentation Overflow strlen, not consistent

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, c99, strlen

I have been searching for answers to this problem for a while, and I cannot seem to find a solution. When the arguments are of different lengths, there is no error. When they are of the same length, the segfault error occurs. The function is meant to compare two strings and return a new string that contains the largest of each ith character. My function is as follows:

```
   char* charMax(char* string1, char* string2) 
   {
        int length1 = strlen(string1);
        printf("%d", length1);
        int length2 = strlen(string2);

        int lengthLarge = length1 >= length2 ? length1 : length2;
        int lengthSmall = length1 <= length2 ? length1 : length2;

        char* largerString = length1 >= length2 ? string1 : string2;
        char* result = malloc(lengthLarge + 1);


        for (int i = 0; i < lengthSmall; i++) 
            result[i] = string1[i] > string2[i] ? string1[i] : string2[i];

        if (length1 != length2) 
        {
            for (int i = lengthSmall; i < lengthLarge; i++) 
                result[i] = largerString[i];

            result[lengthLarge + 1] = '\0';

            return result;

            free(result);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Well, it might have something to do with the fact that when the two strings have exactly the same length your function never returns anything, so it's result is *garbage*. Which is then interpreted as a pointer. And... well... you know what comes next, don't you?

Let's *properly* indent that code and add some commentary, shall we?

```
char* charMax(char* string1, char* string2) {
    int length1 = strlen(string1);
    printf("%d", length1);
    int length2 = strlen(string2);
    int lengthLarge = length1 >= length2 ? length1 : length2;
    int lengthSmall = length1 <= length2 ? length1 : length2;

    char* largerString = length1 >= length2 ? string1 : string2;
    char* result = malloc(lengthLarge + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < lengthSmall; i++) {
        result[i] = string1[i] > string2[i] ? string1[i] : string2[i];
    }
    if (length1 != length2) {
        for (int i = lengthSmall; i < lengthLarge; i++) {
            result[i] = largerString[i];
        }

        result[lengthLarge + 1] = '\0';

        return result;

        free(result); /* uhm, what? this will never execute */
    }

    /* oops - what happens now? who knows? */
}
```

Comment: I put the bracket in the wrong place. What a dumb mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems, Nik's answer points out the major one. Another one is here:

```
result[lengthLarge + 1] = '\0'; // out of bounds! 
// this should be result[lengthLarge] = '\0'
```

Also, this signature is better for your purpose:

```
char* charMax(const char *string1, const char *string2);
```

Comment: Good catch! I *totally* missed that!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am new to C, what is the difference between char* string1 and char *string1? I understand the difference between char string1[], but I did not realize there was another option.

Comment: @user2159044, they are totally same but pointer definition is generally written next to the variable name not the type (`int a, *b` defines an integer and pointer). I actually suggested using `const` to be able to pass literal strings.

Comment: @user2159044 - @perreal was mostly referring to using `const` not to the location of the '*'.  `const` indicates to the caller (of the function) that the value passed will not be modified.